# java-simple-serial-connector (jssc) discard buffer methods

Tags: java, serial-port, jssc

I'm reading data from a hardware through the serial port and I'm using `readString()` method of jssc.

I have used a Timer to get data continuously.
Because of this, whenever I changed the command, the received data is a combination relevant to previous and current commands.

While using C# I have solved this with the help of `SerialPort.DiscardInBuffer()` method.

Are there any methods in jssc equal to `SerialPort.DiscardInBuffer()` and `SerialPort.DiscardOutBuffer()`?

Answer (score 2):

Finally,

```
SerialPort.purgePort(int flags)
```

is what I've been looking for.